# Cycle through selected bones via keyboard shortcut

Tags: armature, bones, selection-tools

Sometimes you have a group of bones selected and you want to animate them or their bone constraints over time, but manually selecting each bone in order to set keyframes on position or constraints is tedious.

If I have multiple, specific bones selected, is there a way to cycle through those specific bones in a loop?

It would be great if there was a workflow similar to how you can <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> to traverse through connected bones, only for a specific bone group's available bones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a shot at making a Blender Add-on to solve this problem:

https://github.com/dancrew32/blender_bone_traversal

1. Select an armature and switch to Pose Mode.
2. Select a subset of bones within the armature.
3. Open the "Bone Traversal" panel, and select "Set Bones" aka `bones.set`
4. Select Next or Prev to cycle through those bones (aka `bones.prev` or `bones.next`)

Seems to be working pretty well! Let me know what you think and if you have ideas for improvements!